# Why does LXX use both "salvation" and "peace" for Hebrew "peace"?

Tags: septuagint, soteriology, shalom

Why does LXX use both "salvation" (Strongs 4991)  and "peace" (Strongs 1515) for Hebrew "peace" (Strongs 8002)?

For example, in Exodus 20:24, the LXX uses 4991:

> θυσιαστήριον ἐκ γῆς ποιήσετέ μοι καὶ θύσετε ἐπ᾽ αὐτοῦ τὰ ὁλοκαυτώματα καὶ τὰ **σωτήρια** ὑμῶν τὰ πρόβατα καὶ τοὺς μόσχους ὑμῶν ἐν παντὶ τόπῳ οὗ ἐὰν ἐπονομάσω τὸ ὄνομά μου ἐκεῖ καὶ ἥξω πρὸς σὲ καὶ εὐλογήσω σε

in the BHS:

> מִזְבַּ֣ח אֲדָמָה֮ תַּעֲשֶׂה־לִּי֒ וְזָבַחְתָּ֣ עָלָ֗יו אֶת־עֹלֹתֶ֨יךָ֙ וְאֶת־**שְׁלָמֶ֔יךָ** אֶת־צֹֽאנְךָ֖ וְאֶת־בְּקָרֶ֑ךָ בְּכָל־הַמָּקֹום֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר אַזְכִּ֣יר אֶת־שְׁמִ֔י אָבֹ֥וא אֵלֶ֖יךָ וּבֵרַכְתִּֽיךָ׃

in Malachi 2:5, the LXX uses 1515:

> ἡ διαθήκη μου ἦν μετ᾽ αὐτοῦ τῆς ζωῆς καὶ τῆς **εἰρήνης** καὶ ἔδωκα αὐτῷ ἐν φόβῳ φοβεῖσθαί με καὶ ἀπὸ προσώπου ὀνόματός μου στέλλεσθαι αὐτόν

in Hebrew: 2:5

> בְּרִיתִי הָיְתָה אִתֹּו הַֽחַיִּים **וְהַשָּׁלֹום** וָאֶתְּנֵֽם־לֹו מֹורָא וַיִּֽירָאֵנִי וּמִפְּנֵי שְׁמִי נִחַת הֽוּא׃

Did the LXX use 4991 **σωτήρια**  in Torah, but 1515 **εἰρήνης**  in the remaining Hebrew texts?

Is it the same as the answer to "Why does Numbers 29:39 (LXX) refer to “your salvation” instead of “peace offerings”?

See Malachi 2:5. In the context of **Covenant** (My covenant (Strongs h1285) בְּרִיתִי, LXX uses 1515 **εἰρήνης** instead of 4991 **σωτήρια**. This makes me think that the answer to the question regarding Numbers 29:39 is not related to Covenant, but to Torah. (?)

Comment: The Hebrew that you highlighted in the first quote, תעשה לי means "make for me". Is this what you intended to highlight? I am a near native Hebrew speaker but know no Greek.

Comment: I'm looking for "and peace"
Phrase
h7965   
with the root of שָׁלוֹם shalowm;

Comment: FIxed. שלומיך "shlomecha" means "your reconciliation offerings" or "your peace offerings" as "shalom" can mean "peace", "reconciliation", "wholeness", like שלם meaning "complete", "perfect", "without anything missing or damaged". Going off-line for the Tabernacles holiday now in Jerusalem.

Answer (score 2):

The original Hebrew would have been unvocalized, so that what would have appeared in the original text would have been something like שׁלם (*šlm*). This has a number of different vocalizations:

- שָׁלַם  (*šā·lǎm*)
- שָׁלֵם (*šā·lēm*)
- שַׁלֻּם (*šǎl·lǔm*)
- שְׁלָם (*šelām*)
- שֶׁלֶם (*šě·lěm*)
- שָׁלֹם (*šā·lōm*)
- שָׁלֻם (*šā·lǔm*)
- שִׁלֵּם (*šil·lēm*)

Many discrepancies between the Septuagint - compiled in the 2nd century BC - and the Masoretic Hebrew Text - compiled several centuries later - can be explained, I think, by differences in how the translators/transcribers thought the underlying proto-Hebrew text should be vocalized.

The medieval Masoretic Text for Exodus 20:24 imputes the vocalization שֶׁלֶם (*šě·lěm*).  It would seem, however, that the Alexandrian Jews understood the older proto-Hebrew text to be (using Masoretic notation) שָׁלוֹם (*šā·lôm*), rather than שֶׁלֶם (*šě·lěm*).   This word's meaning does, in fact, include "safeness" and "health" - either of which would be indicated by σωτήρια.

The underlying Masoretic Text in Malachi, on the other hand, is שָׁלוֹם (*šā·lôm*).  Here the issue seems to be not a disagreement on how the underlying Hebrew should be vocalized, but rather the scope of the Hebrew word itself.  According to Swanson's *Dictionary of Biblical Languages with Semantic Domains*, the underlying word's meanings also includes not "peace" (e.g. 1 Samuel 1:17), "completeness" (Jeremiah 13:19), "satisfaction" (Exodus 18:23), "friend" (Jeremiah 20:10), and "blessing" (Jeremiah 16:5).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that the LXX is older than the Masoretic.

Comment: Perhaps [this article](https://blogs.ancientfaith.com/departinghoreb/masoretic-hebrew-vs-septuagint-part-1/) might be of interest

Comment: Do you have any information about the "sacrifice of well-being" or "offering of well-being" found throughout Exodus, Leviticus, etc.?

Comment: Which specific verses are you referring to?